# Potential of central force - Does it matter that $n$ is an integer in $\rho^n$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In problem 6G-2 of the following link to a pdf-file from ocw.mit.edu ([Link](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/4.-triple-integrals-and-surface-integrals-in-3-space/part-b-flux-and-the-divergence-theorem/problem-set-11/MIT18_02SC_SupProb6.pdf)) it is pointed out that $n$ is an integer.

> **Problem 6G-2:**
>
> Show that the fields $\mathbf{F} = \rho^n(x\hat\imath + y\hat\jmath + z\hat k)$, where $\rho = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$, are gradient fields for any value of the integer $n$. (Hint: use $\rho_x = x/\rho$, etc.)

My question is now: Does it matter that $n$ is an integer? Can't it just be any real number without changing the calculation and results? I'd be glad at any help.